# how to alter iframe base property using javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iframe from an external source. I want to alter it (with javascript) so all links are opened with another absolute URL. I'm assuming the best approach is to modify the base property (element)

For example, assuming I embed stackoverflow.com as:
`<iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com"/>`

I want that when a user clicks the links, for example `<a id="nav-askquestion" href="/questions/ask">Ask Question</a>`, they will be opened in `http://mysite.com`, for example `http://mysite.com/questions/ask`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is entirely impossible due to the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

You would have to fetch the external HTML page using a proxy script on your local server. There is no other way of gaining access to the page's links or setting a `base` property.